# Run standalone.bat from Wildfly like background process command line?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, wildfly-10

I'm having trouble installing Wildfly as a service.

So I need to be able to run the Wildlfy in standalone mode as a temporary solution, but I want it to run in the background since it is a shared server and by mistake someone can close the console:

```
C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat --silent --close-cmd-after-start
```

Basically I want to be able to close the terminal once the `standalone.bat` is executed

Comment: Maybe this can help https://serverfault.com/questions/121979/tools-to-run-a-background-process-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Please try a Google search on `run wildfly as windows service`.

Comment: @lit I tried to install as a service, but I have a problem due to the fact that the user I use is not local, but it is part of the windows AD and that generates certain problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution thanks to the suggestion of [Eriksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)

```
cd C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin>

powershell -c "saps standalone.bat -windowstyle hidden"
```

Comment: That just minimizes the console to the taskbar. You need other tools such as Python or PowerShell if you want to hide the console or run detached. Have you looked at the contents of this batch script? Maybe it's just running an executable that isn't actually console program.

Comment: if you have a better suggestion, please share with me your idea. I don't have any more ideas for do this

Comment: For a hidden window, try: `powershell -c "saps standalone.bat -windowstyle hidden"`

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

In case of `linux` you can use something like this one `./standalone.sh &` . So, you can try

```
C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat --silent --close-cmd-after-start &
```

which helps to run your application on background.

Comment: I'll try and I'll let you know the result